# Why is my Expression for Array Length Just Returning 1?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in Unity, and just noticed an odd bug that comes up sometimes. What's happening is that a string array that I'm instantiating is being created too short, even though the log messages I'm writing confirm that the expression *should* be creating a larger array.

Here's the relevant snippet of code:

```
Debug.Log("hero.power = " + hero.power.ToString());
Debug.Log("allyPower = " + allyPower.ToString());
Debug.Log("opponent.power = " + opponent.power.ToString());
int max = Mathf.Max(hero.power + allyPower, opponent.power);
report.flips[hero.name] = new string[hero.power + allyPower];
report.flips[opponent.name] = new string[opponent.power];
Debug.Log("max = " + max.ToString());
Debug.Log("report.flips[hero.name].Length = " + report.flips[hero.name].Length.ToString());
```

And the output this creates in Unity:

[image: Sample Debug Log Output]

This shows that `hero.power` is `3`, and `allyPower` is `0` but instead of creating a `string[3]` it creates a `string[1]`.

Is there something about using expressions to determine the length of arrays that's causing an issue here? I temporarily changed to this:

```
int heroArrayLength = hero.power + allyPower;
report.flips[hero.name] = new string[heroArrayLength];
```

And it seems to have helped, though the bug was erratic before so I'm not entirely certain it's fixed. And even if it is, I'm still unclear what the actual cause is.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: is there any chance that `hero.name==opponent.name` ? in which case you're setting the same "flips" twice, and the second time it will be set to length 1 (`opponent.power` is 1)

Comment: @MarcGravell ...oh my god you're right. The name is set from user input, so I just mash keys to quickly enter values and move on without thinking about it. So it's absolutely possible that I'm just accidentally entering the same thing twice in certain cases.

Comment: it is amazing how many times "asdf" gets into systems :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `hero.name` is the same as `opponent.name`, then:

```
report.flips[hero.name] = new string[hero.power + allyPower];
report.flips[opponent.name] = new string[opponent.power];
```

will both be setting the same "flips" (whatever "flips" is/are), and the second time "wins". Since `opponent.power` is `1`, the final array will be of length `1`, which means that `report.flips[hero.name]` will be length `1`.